# Simple bufferoverflow using scanf (Mac OS X 10.6.5 64-Bit)

Tags: c, macos, 64-bit, buffer, overflow

For educational purposes I'm trying to accomplish a bufferoverflow that directs the program to a different adress.

This is the c-program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void secret1(void) {
 puts("You found the secret function No. 1!\n");
}

int main () {
 char string[2];
 puts("Input: ");
 scanf("%s", string);
 printf("You entered %s.\n", string);
 return 0;
}
```

I used gdb to find the address of secret1 as well es the offset the my variable string to the RIP. Using this information I created the following python-exploit:

```
import struct
rip = 0x0000000100000e40
print("A"*24 + struct.pack("<q", rip))
```

So far everything works - the program jumps to secret1 and then crashes with "Segmentation fault".

HOWEVER, if I extend my program like this:

```
...
void secret1(void) {
 puts("You found the secret function No. 1!\n");
}

void secret2(void) {
 puts("You found the secret function No. 2!\n");
}

void secret3(void) {
 puts("You found the secret function No. 3!\n");
}
...
```

...it SegFaults WITHOUT jumping to any of the functions, even tho the new fake RIPs are correct (i.e. 0x0000000100000d6c for secret1, 0x0000000100000d7e for secret2). The offsets stay the same as far as gdb told me (or don't they?).

I noticed that none of my attempts work when the program is "big enough" to place the secret-functions in the memory-area ending with 0x100000 **d** .. - it works like a charm tho, when they are somewhere in 0x100000 **e** ..

It also works with more than one secret function when I compile it in 32-Bit-mode (addresses changed accordingly) but not in 64-Bit-mode.

```
-fno-stack-protector // doesn't make any difference.
```

Can anybody please explain this odd behaviour to me? Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps creating multiple hidden functions puts them all in a page of memory without execute permission... try explicitly giving RWX permission to that page using mprotect. Could be a number of other things, but this is the first issue I would address.

As for the -fno-stack-protector gcc option, I was convinced for a while this was obfuscated on gcc 4.2.1. But after playing with it a bit more, I have learned that in order for canary stack protection to be enabled, sizeof(buffer) >= 8 must be true. Additionally, it must be a char buffer, unless you specify the -fstack-protector-all or -fnostack-protector-all options, which enable canaries even for functions that don't contain char buffers. I'm running OS X 10.6.5 64-bit with aforementioned gcc version and on a buffer overflow exploit snippet I'm writing, my stack changes when compiling with -fstack-protector-all versus compiling with no relevant options (probably because the function being exploited doesn't have a char buffer). So if you want to be certain that this feature is either disabled or enabled, make sure to use the -all variants of the options.